# Why is this implementation of Luhn's algorithm not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, luhn

I was creating a function for Luhn's algorithm in Javascript.
Here is my code:

```
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];


// Add your functions below:
function validateCred(arr){
  let newArr = [];
  newArr.push(arr[arr.length - 1]);
  for(let i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
    let x = arr[i];
    // console.log(x);
    x *= 2;
    if(x > 9){
      x -= 9;
    }
    // console.log(x);
    newArr.push(x);
    // console.log(newArr);
  } 
  // console.log(newArr);
   let sum = 0;
   newArr.forEach(num => sum += num);
   console.log(sum);
//    if(sum % 10 === 0){
//     return true;
//   } else {
//      return false;
//  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(validateCred(valid1));
```

This is not my original code, but as you can see `validateCred` is my function.
The if statement is actually supposed to give a result of true, but it is giving false,
so I was wondering where I went wrong.
The console.log's in here were helping me figure out what went wrong,
so here is the output of them.
I cut the code to see what the function was doing with the array, I checked and everything was good. Even the sum was working.
So I was left wondering whether the array is wrong,
but when I inputed the same array in GeeksForGeeks's implementation,
It gave true!
So what went wrong?

Comment: "Take the original number and starting from the rightmost digit moving left, double the value of every **second** digit (including the rightmost digit)." (emphasis mine)

Comment: But are you saying that we need to start this sequence after the check digit?

Comment: Here's what my list told:
Starting from the farthest digit to the right, AKA the check digit, iterate to the left.
As you iterate to the left, every other digit is doubled (the check digit is not doubled). If the number is greater than 9 after doubling, subtract 9 from its value.
Sum up all the digits in the credit card number.
If the sum modulo 10 is 0 (if the sum divided by 10 has a remainder of 0) then the number is valid, otherwise, it’s invalid.

Comment: That's right. `valid1` should give you a sum of `80`, which is indeed a multiple of 10.

Comment: wait, so you are saying that i should be arr.length - 2

Comment: It may be easier to create a reversed copy of the number (`const copy = [...arr].reverse()`) and iterate over that, because then you can use `i%2` to decide whether to double or not. You could also pre-calculate the "double but subtract 9 if too big" thing and have an array like `const doubled = [0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9]`, then reference `doubled[x]` to skip all of the maths.

Comment: but here's the thing: i % 2 might or might not work depending on arr.length

Comment: That's why you reverse the array first.

Comment: so maybe I should test arr.length and then do I % 2

Comment: With that in place, you can just loop over the array once, and do `sum += (i%2) ? doubled[x] : x` to add up the digits in the correct way.

Comment: okay then, I'll try it

Comment: Hi niet, i used two for loops in my implementation, but I read your's as well, thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could move all your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to take Niet's credits, so if he posts his comments as an anwser, you should accept his. I'm posting this only two show two shorter alternatives using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

The main problem with your algorithm is (as Niet already said) you are doubling *each* digit, instead of only every other digit.

Variant 1 with reversing the card number

```
function checkCard(arr) {
  return arr.slice().reverse() 
    .reduce((a, c, i) => a + (i % 2 == 0
      ? c
      : (c < 5 ? 2 * c : 2 * c - 9)), 
      0) % 10 == 0;
}
```

I used `arr.slice().reverse()` because `reverse` works in place. So to keep `arr` in the original order, copy it first. `reduce` will then sum up the digits. For every even index (0,2,4,...) in the *reversed array* it will just add the current digit `c`. For every odd (1,3,5,...) index, it will add either `2*c` or `2*c-9`, depending on whether `2*c > 9`.

Variant 2 without reversing the card number

```
function checkCard2(arr) {
  const p = arr.length % 2
  return arr.reduce((a,c,i) => a + (i % 2 != p 
    ? c
    :  (c < 5 ? 2 * c : 2 * c - 9)),
    0) % 10 == 0;
}
```

Because Luhn's original algorithm starts couting from the rightmost digit, if we start from the leftmost digit (ie without reversing the number), we have to act differently on numbers of even or odd length. For numbers of odd length, we must double the digits at odd indexes (1,3,5,...), for even length we must double the digits at even indexes (0,2,4,...). That's what the `p` is for. It will be `0` for even length, and `1` for odd length. So if `i % 2 == p` we must double the current digit, otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For showing how to make my code better :)